# How to detect current orientation to rotate UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I am implement taking photo function and I'm having the following issue.

After taking the photo, I have to crop a thumbnail from original image to make an avatar icon. But it's not good if user takes the photo in landscape.

Step:

1. Turn on camera.
2. Rotate the iPhone to right (so that the camera is in landscape mode).
3. Take picture.
4. I get UIImage with bad orientation. Therefore, thumbnail is not good.

How I can detect the orientation to rotate UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

Try Below code

```
if (image.size.width > image.size.height ) // Landscape
    {

    }
else   // Portrait
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to get the orientation of your device.
According to Device orientation you can set Image orientation

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

Answer (score 1):

UIImage has a `size` property. You can use this to find the `height` and `width` of the `image`.

Therefore, if `height` > `width` then `image` is in portrait else landscape

Comment: Thanks for helping, but how I know this is right landscape or left landscape?

Comment: are you selecting the image from UIImagePickerController?

Comment: No, i use external camera lib. https://github.com/Aevit/SCCaptureCamera/tree/master/SCCaptureCameraDemo/SCCaptureCamera

Comment: `UIImage` only gets **image data** from the camera or photos folder and not the orientation details. The image can be png, jpeg or whatever, it doesn't know the orientation of the image. So there is no way to find the if the image is landscape or portrait

Comment: But can we detect the current orientation while user is in camera session? Because sometime they want take portrait mode, sometime landscape.

Comment: In your library's `SCCaptureCameraController.m` class you can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` to get the device orientation. Also in the same class you have delegate method implemented at the bottom - `(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info`, you can try @tanuj's answer and check if it returns you correct orientation.

Comment: I know these code line, but it's always portrait mode although I rotate my iPhone to landscape. This makes me confusing.

Comment: which line of code you are using to find the orientation?

Comment: UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
        if (orientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
            
            CGFloat degree = 0;
            if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
                degree = 180;// M_PI;
            } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
                degree = -90;// -M_PI_2;
            } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                degree = 90;// M_PI_2;
            }
        }

Comment: The problem here: UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation  , the value is always portrait although I rotate the iPhone to take photo.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue then?

Comment: did you try doing `NSLog` for `[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation`? Can you try it if not?

Comment: Yes, i try and it always return portrait although I rotate the iPhone left, right orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#pragma mark - Image Picker Controller delegate methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    switch (chosenImage.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUp: //Left
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown: //Right
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft: //Down
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight: //Up
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, bro! But I use external camera library: https://github.com/Aevit/SCCaptureCamera/tree/master/SCCaptureCameraDemo/SCCaptureCamera How I can detect mode when user rotate (left, right) the iPhone and take picture?